# Spresense SDK にある mkspk のソースコードはどこにありますか？ / Where is the source code of mkspk?

Tags: spresense

GitHub にある Sony の [Spresense SDK](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense) に含まれる `mkspk` には64bit用のバイナリ実行ファイルしかありません。
私は32bit環境のLinux上で開発しており、これのソースコードを探しています。`mkspk-v0.17` のソースコードを手に入れることは出来ますか？

（英語版 StackOverflow ではオフトピックとされたため、日本語版で質問しています。以上は下記英文の概要です）

---

#### some source code is missing on github

One utility is preventing me from developing on 32bit Linux securely. The mkspr executable has no sources. This has two issues, as it is X64 (64bit) only binary, and I don't like running code on my machine that I can't be sure is not nefarious. I also would be able to develop on Raspberry pi and other non x86 based computers.

So far, I have migrated to 32bit everything else, including the binary wrapped python3.5 flash_writer, which was very easy to decompile back to source, and is gpl2, and also is not available as source.

Any chance of Mr. Shunichi or SONY releasing the source for mkspk-v0.17? I also have a few bugs to report, but more on that after I get the source code.

Apologies for asking here in English, but the people on the English stackoverflow were rude and deleted my question for no good reason.

@Spresense please open ability to report bugs and do support requests on GitHub so that questions like this can be asked without disturbing the stackoverflow community.

(google translated)
@spresense バグを報告する機能を開いて、GitHubのリクエストをサポートしてください。そうすれば、stackoverflowコミュニティを妨害することなく、このような質問をすることができます。

Comment: 補足: このご質問に関係している議論がメタに投稿されています: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2830/19110

Comment: 英文投稿の翻訳に関しては[過去に議論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2309/3054)がありましたが、今回は質問者があえて日本語版で質問したことが明確なため、日本語で要約を追加いたしました。
再オープンに投票いたします。

Comment: 英語版での質問はこちらの様ですが、(本家での)信用度が足りないのでクローズされた経緯までは確認できませんでした。 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934825/sony-spresense-source-code-is-missing-on-github

Comment: @cubick さん、使用されているオフトピック理由のテンプレはこちら「"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow」ちょっと実態と使われているテンプレが違うように思うんですが、質問内容が「自分のプログラミング上の課題を解決する」と言う体裁ではなく、「SONYにソースコードの開示を求める」ものだったのでオフトピックにされたものと思われます。ちなみに私はご本人が自分から動かない限り再オープンするべきではないと言う立場です。

Comment: en:
qemu is not an option for me. I am not using any mainstream distribution. I have tried this in the past without any success. qemu does not build on my system.

google translated:
qemuは私のための選択肢ではありません。 私は主流の配布を使用していません。 私はこれまで何の成功もなしにこれを試してきました。 qemuは私のシステム上に構築されていません。

Comment: 質問者ご本人がオフトピックの理由を解消されるよう動かれたようなので、再オープンに投票しました。私的には内容がオントピックかどうか疑念があるのですが、再オープンした上で改めて日本語版コミュニティで判断されるべき事柄だろうと思います。

Comment: 質問そのものは問題ないと思いますが、「GitHubでのissuesを受け付けるようにして欲しい」に関しては、[直接SONYに問い合わせ](https://developer.sony.com/contact-us)た方がいい結果が得られるんじゃないかなと思います。英語版でクローズされてしまったのもこの部分が原因じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick I would have done this if possible. All technical support links lead to stackoverflow which is an unfortunate choice made by SONY
私は可能ならばこれをやったでしょう。 すべてのテクニカルサポートリンクは、SONYの残念な選択であるstackoverflowにつながります。